# Webrequest C# JavaScript enabled

Tags: javascript, c#, webrequest

some days before I could get HTML source code  from a web page by URL with webrequest from c# but now i can't. I receve a message That says that : enable JavaScript to view the web page content. How can I request a web page with JavaScript enabled from webrequest c#? Sorry for my pior english I'm Brasilian.

Comment: The problem is that, with modern frameworks, many websites page now consist only now of some JS scripts which will fetch the site content asynchronously (AJAX-like), and then the DOM is dynamically created. So, it's true that you actually need Javascript to show the interesting contents of the we bpage.
 This is just a comment to help you understand the problem, as it doesn't give any clue to help answering your question.

Comment: If you want to do it with Webrequest, then you should have some Javascript engine that your C# code can call, and execute the requests, etc... Bascially, you would recreate a core part of the browser.s

Comment: related (possibly duplicate) : [Scraping dynamic web content in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245294/scraping-dynamic-content)

Comment: (as I understand from the previous link, you can use IE engine from your C# code to act as a headless browser, and do all the complicated browser stuff to correctly load the page)

Comment: Thanks.  But I gave up. I triyed some solution like htmlagilitypack  and   anglesharp but didn't work. This consumed 3 days of hard word. The solution was using webroser from Windows form aplication and change threads behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't solution for your question; WebRequest can't enable JS in that website; maybe you have to use WebView2 to solve this problem.